# does Grails controllers consume json in the body?

Tags: grails

I have auto-scaffolded my controllers,

does the update method automatically consume and persist a JSON domain object inside the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does you just have to mention the correct Content-Type. The credit for this answer should go to shaydel.

Comment: i would disagree,from my tests,the convertor does consume and later persist domain object by default. all you need is to include the json in the http put/post body.

Comment: It looks like you are right, I have updated the answer.